# Inconsistent results of CUDA program after several times of executions

Tags: c, cuda

### Description

I was trying to perform matrix summation with 2D grid and 2D blocks on GPU and got different results after several executions of the program. Any explanation or fixes for this behavior will be helpful, thanks.

### Detail

Most of the time the result on CPU is consistent with the result on GPU. But sometimes (say, right after the OS started up) the program tells that the results are inconsistent. But all the executions after that will yield consistent results (and run seemingly faster). 
I've yet to find a guaranteed way to reproduce such behavior. I tried rebooting the OS again but the first execution of the program yielded consistent result.

### Code

The main function performs summation on two 2^10 by 2^10 matrices on CPU and GPU (with a 2^5 by 2^5 grid with 2^5 by 2^5 blocks) and compares the results.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE !FALSE
double *mallocMatrix(const int row, const int column)
{
    return (double*)malloc(row*column*sizeof(double));
}

void matrixInit(double *matrix, const int row, const int column)
{
    ;
}


int matEqual(double *mat1, double *mat2, const int row, const int column)
{
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<column;j++)
        {
            int k=i*column+j;
            if(mat1[k]!=mat2[k])
            {
                printf("Entry %d doens't match.\n",k);
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void matrixSumCpu(double *m1, double *m2, double *n, const int row, const int column)
{
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<column; j++)
        {
            int k = i * column + j;
            n[k]=m1[k]+m2[k];
        }
    }
}

__global__ void _2dGrid2dBlockMatSum(double *m1, double *m2, double *n, const int row, const int column)
{
    int rowIndex=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    int columnIndex=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
    if(rowIndex<row&&columnIndex<column)
    {
        int i=rowIndex*column+columnIndex;//flatten
        n[i]=m1[i]+m2[i];
    }
}


void checkGpuMalloc(cudaError_t code)
{
    if(code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        exit(-1);
        printf("CUDA ERROR occured. ");
    }
}

void printMatrix(double *mat, const int row, const int column)
{
    const int rowToPrint=3;
    const int columnToPrint=6;
    for(int i=0;i<rowToPrint;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<columnToPrint;j++)
            printf("%lf", mat[i*column+j]);
        if(column>columnToPrint)
            printf("...");
        printf("\n");
    }
    if(row>rowToPrint)
        printf("...\n");
}

int main()
{
    int row=1<<10, column=1<<10;
    double *h_m1=NULL, *h_m2=NULL,*h_n1=NULL, *h_n2=NULL;//n=m1+m2
    h_m1=mallocMatrix(row, column);
    h_m2=mallocMatrix(row, column);
    h_n1=mallocMatrix(row, column);
    h_n2=mallocMatrix(row, column);
    if(h_m1==NULL||h_m2==NULL||h_n1==NULL||h_n2==NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate enough memory on CPU\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    matrixInit(h_m1,row,column);
    matrixInit(h_m2,row,column);
    printf("Summing matrices on CPU...\n");
    matrixSumCpu(h_m1,h_m2,h_n1,row,column);
    double *d_m1=NULL, *d_m2=NULL, *d_n=NULL;
    checkGpuMalloc(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_m1, row*column*sizeof(double)));
    checkGpuMalloc(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_m2, row*column*sizeof(double)));
    checkGpuMalloc(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_n, row*column*sizeof(double)));
    cudaMemcpy(d_m1, h_m1, row*column*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_m2, h_m2, row*column*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    printf("Summing matrices on GPU with 2D grid and 2D blocks.\n");
    _2dGrid2dBlockMatSum<<<(1<<5,1<<5),(1<<5, 1<<5)>>>(d_m1, d_m2, d_n, row, column);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();    
    cudaMemcpy(h_n2, d_n, row*column*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if(matEqual(h_n1, h_n2, row, column))
        printf("Matrices match.\n");
    else
    {
        printf("Matrices don't match.\nResult on CPU:\n");
        printMatrix(h_n1, row, column);
        printf("Result on GPU:");
        printMatrix(h_n2, row, column);
    }
    free(h_m1);
    free(h_m2);
    free(h_n1);
    free(h_n2);
    cudaFree(d_m1);
    cudaFree(d_m2);
    cudaFree(d_n);
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does, and when I compile your code, the compiler issues a warning on this line:

```
_2dGrid2dBlockMatSum<<<(1<<5,1<<5),(1<<5, 1<<5)>>>(d_m1, d_m2, d_n, row, column);
```

You should be doing something like this:

```
_2dGrid2dBlockMatSum<<<dim3(1<<5,1<<5),dim3(1<<5, 1<<5)>>>(d_m1, d_m2, d_n, row, column);
```

This:

```
dim3(1<<5,1<<5)
```

is not the same as this:

```
(1<<5,1<<5)
```

The C++ compiler evaluates that last expression producing some kind of junk you're not expecting (a scalar quantity of 32, instead of a 2D quantity (32,32)).

Why is your `matrixInit` function empty?

If you want to force your code to fail all the time, add some matrix initialization:

```
void matrixInit(double *matrix, const int row, const int column)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        matrix[i*column+j] = 1;
}
```

and add this line before your kernel call:

```
cudaMemset(d_n, 0, row*column*sizeof(double));
```

Then compile and run that, and it will fail.

After that, then make the `dim3` change as I suggested, and it will fix it.

Here is the fixed example:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE !FALSE
double *mallocMatrix(const int row, const int column)
{
    return (double*)malloc(row*column*sizeof(double));
}

void matrixInit(double *matrix, const int row, const int column)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        matrix[i*column+j] = 1;
}


int matEqual(double *mat1, double *mat2, const int row, const int column)
{
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<column;j++)
        {
            int k=i*column+j;
            if(mat1[k]!=mat2[k])
            {
                printf("Entry %d doens't match.\n",k);
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void matrixSumCpu(double *m1, double *m2, double *n, const int row, const int column)
{
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<column; j++)
        {
            int k = i * column + j;
            n[k]=m1[k]+m2[k];
        }
    }
}

__global__ void _2dGrid2dBlockMatSum(double *m1, double *m2, double *n, const int row, const int column)
{
    int rowIndex=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    int columnIndex=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
    if(rowIndex<row&&columnIndex<column)
    {
        int i=rowIndex*column+columnIndex;//flatten
        n[i]=m1[i]+m2[i];
    }
}


void checkGpuMalloc(cudaError_t code)
{
    if(code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        exit(-1);
        printf("CUDA ERROR occured. ");
    }
}

void printMatrix(double *mat, const int row, const int column)
{
    const int rowToPrint=3;
    const int columnToPrint=6;
    for(int i=0;i<rowToPrint;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<columnToPrint;j++)
            printf("%lf", mat[i*column+j]);
        if(column>columnToPrint)
            printf("...");
        printf("\n");
    }
    if(row>rowToPrint)
        printf("...\n");
}

int main()
{
    int row=1<<10, column=1<<10;
    double *h_m1=NULL, *h_m2=NULL,*h_n1=NULL, *h_n2=NULL;//n=m1+m2
    h_m1=mallocMatrix(row, column);
    h_m2=mallocMatrix(row, column);
    h_n1=mallocMatrix(row, column);
    h_n2=mallocMatrix(row, column);
    if(h_m1==NULL||h_m2==NULL||h_n1==NULL||h_n2==NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate enough memory on CPU\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    matrixInit(h_m1,row,column);
    matrixInit(h_m2,row,column);
    printf("Summing matrices on CPU...\n");
    matrixSumCpu(h_m1,h_m2,h_n1,row,column);
    double *d_m1=NULL, *d_m2=NULL, *d_n=NULL;
    checkGpuMalloc(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_m1, row*column*sizeof(double)));
    checkGpuMalloc(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_m2, row*column*sizeof(double)));
    checkGpuMalloc(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_n, row*column*sizeof(double)));
    cudaMemcpy(d_m1, h_m1, row*column*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_m2, h_m2, row*column*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemset(d_n, 0, row*column*sizeof(double));
    printf("Summing matrices on GPU with 2D grid and 2D blocks.\n");
    printf("%d\n", (1<<5,1<<5));
    _2dGrid2dBlockMatSum<<<(1<<5,1<<5),(1<<5, 1<<5)>>>(d_m1, d_m2, d_n, row, column);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(h_n2, d_n, row*column*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if(matEqual(h_n1, h_n2, row, column))
        printf("Matrices match.\n");
    else
    {
        printf("Matrices don't match.\nResult on CPU:\n");
        printMatrix(h_n1, row, column);
        printf("Result on GPU:");
        printMatrix(h_n2, row, column);
    }
    free(h_m1);
    free(h_m2);
    free(h_n1);
    free(h_n2);
    cudaFree(d_m1);
    cudaFree(d_m2);
    cudaFree(d_n);
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```